# How to replace variable in text depending on heading level?

Tags: lua, markdown, pandoc

I have text in markdown. A line anywhere in the text can be repeated in the %rep% variable. There is a heading before the text. Heading have 4 levels.
How to replace %rep% value depending on header level?

If the heading is level 1, then %rep% is set to "Section".
If the heading is level 2, then the %rep% variable is set to "Subsection".
If the heading is level 3, then %rep% is set to "Point".
If the heading is level 4, then the %rep% variable is set to "Subitem".

Markdown example

```
---
title: my title
---

# Chapter 1

Text with variable %rep%.

## Subsection

### Paragraph

#### Subparagraph

Text with %rep% variable.
```

output result:

```
# Chapter 1

Text with variable **Section**.

## Subsection

### Paragraph

#### Subparagraph

Text with **Subitem** variable.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did not work as expected? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing your best attempt to solve this problem on your own.